# MongoDB - db does not show any collection after mongoimport

Tags: json, mongodb, collections

I am actually exploring MongoDB and mapReduce within, but I got a problem.
The installation of mongodb was successful. 
After that I tried to `import a json` file typing these 2 commands before calling mongo in terminal(I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) :

```
$ wget http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json  

$ mongoimport --db mapreduce --collection zips --file zips.json
```

Then I call command :

```
$ mongo
```

I got these warnings :

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5  
connecting to: test  
Server has startup warnings:  
2014-11-04T20:15:12.280+0100 [initandlisten]  
2014-11-04T20:15:12.280+0100 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.    
2014-11-04T20:15:12.280+0100 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).  
2014-11-04T20:15:12.280+0100 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.  
2014-11-04T20:15:12.280+0100 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit   
2014-11-04T20:15:12.280+0100 [initandlisten]
```

And now when I want to show the collections, I normally type :

> **show collections**

But it doesn't show any collection. Like this :

show collections

>

And when I type

> **show dbs**

I got on terminal:

```
admin      (empty)    
local      0.078GB     
mapreduce  0.078GB     
test       (empty)    
zips       (empty)
```

Which means that the database zips is empty, but when I open it, there are lots of documents in.

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mongoimport --db mapreduce --collection zips --file zips.json
```

This command imports data from the file `zips.json` into a collection named `zips` residing in the `mapreduce` database.

> *And now when I want to show the collections, I normally type : show collections But it doesn't show any collection. Like this :*

By default when you open a new `mongo` client, it uses the `test` database. i.e all operations done **without switching** the database will be carried out on the `test` database.

Since the `mongoimport` command executes the operations on the `mapreduce` database and not in the default `test` database, you see no collections in the `test` database.

When you do `show dbs`, it lists all the databases present. You can see the new `mapreduce` database being listed there. The `zips` that you see here is a database you might have accidentally created, and not the collection into which you have imported the data into.

> *Which means that the database zips is empty, but when I open it, there are lots of documents in.*

Yes, the **database** named `zips` is empty. What you are looking is for is the `zips` **collection**.
So, you need to issue the command: `use mapreduce;`, to switch to the `mapreduce` database first. There, when you issue `show collections`, you can see the `zips` collection with the imported data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BatScream. After lots of trying I also realized that it's obvious to change the database, because the import refers to the database mapreduce and not to zips. Thanks also for  your explication. I hope this could help to others also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That was a great explanation by @BatScream.I would like to add a little more to @BatScream.

**You tried the import as below:**

```
$ mongoimport --db mapreduce --collection zips --file zips.json
```

So your `.json` file will be imported into the `zips` collection in the `mapreduce` database.To view the imported data give the following commands:

```
>show dbs
>use mapreduce
>show collections
>db.zips.find()
```

Now the imported data will be present in the `zips`collection.

**Why those warnings?**

32-bit MongoDB processes are limited to about 2 gb of data. The reason for this is that the MongoDB storage engine uses memory-mapped files for performance.So it cannot possibly use the journal much.Also journaling will be off by default in 32bit.Do not disable journaling in mongodb.Never use 32 bit for productions.To know a lot about journaling check my blog post [for a clear idea](http://jerwinroy.blogspot.in/2015/02/mongodb-journal-concepts.html).